# IOS Safari not scrolling to top when changing backbone page

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, safari, scrollbar

when navigating between the application pages the IOS Safari scrollbar will stay at the last position. So when scrolling it will remember that position when scrolling between pages. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? That isn't happening on all of the other browsers.

The current solution is to do

```
App.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
onRoute: function(route,url,params){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
```

});

That forces use to use trigger:true when navigating in Backbone and it's not a practice that we like. Any ideas?

thanks for thelp